# Building a Geosearch Autocomplete like Airbnb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am trying to make a search field like Airbnb where you start typing and it will auto-complete to what your typing.  I started using [jQuery Geocomplete](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/)  But I can't seem to find a way to style CSS for it.

Can anyone point me to a way I can either implement my own geo-location auto-complete or something that has been already built that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google maps Places API's `Autocomplete for Addresses and Search Terms` gives you a degree of styling on the autocomplete search box, refer to the [Style the Autocomplete and SearchBox widgets](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete) section for CSS classes for Autocomplete and SearchBox widgets.

Also I created a quick demo where I colored the Autocomplete the same way as Airbnb does. Hopes this help.

http://jsfiddle.net/agwsvk08/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of AutoComplete along with styling for the map and input elements. Should be a good starting point for you.

Styled

```js
var FIDDLE_MAP = 'f_style';

function initialize() {

  var featureOpts = [{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#444444"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#f2f2f2"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": -100
    }, {
      "lightness": 45
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "simplified"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [{
      "color": "#e15454"
    }, {
      "visibility": "on"
    }]
  }];


  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, FIDDLE_MAP]
    },
    mapTypeId: FIDDLE_MAP
  });

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'F Style'
  };

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(FIDDLE_MAP, customMapType);

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.621404, -74.033231),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.752613, -73.632917));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        content: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(-5, -35)
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: markers[i].content,
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(pointer, infoWindow) {
        return function() {
          infoWindow.open(map, pointer);
        };
      }(marker, infoWindow));

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
 html,
 body,
 #map-canvas {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px
 }
 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #f00;
 }
 :-moz-placeholder {
   /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #f00;
 }
 ::-moz-placeholder {
   /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #f00;
 }
 :-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: #f00;
 }
 .controls {
   margin-top: 16px;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 32px;
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 }
 #pac-input {
   background-color: #fff;
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 300;
   margin-top: 0px;
   padding: 0 11px 0 20px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   border-bottom: 6px solid #f00;
   color: #F00;
   -webkit-transition: width 200ms, height 200ms, background-color 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
   transition: width 200ms, height 200ms, background-color 200ms, transform 200ms;
 }
 #pac-input:focus {
   border-bottom: 6px solid #1c1c1c;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
   color: #1c1c1c;
   font-weight: 400;
   height: 55px;
 }
 .pac-container {
   border-bottom: 9px solid #F00;
   font-family: Roboto;
 }
 .pac-matched {
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #F00;
 }
 .pac-matched:hover {
   color: #40B7B8;
 }
 .pac-item {
   font-size: 16px;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
 #type-selector {
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #4d90fe;
   padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
 }
 #type-selector label {
   font-family: Roboto;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-weight: 300;
 }
 #target {
   width: 345px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search for Something">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
```